# Simplicial sets, injectivity

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, functors

Let $X\colon \Delta^{op}\to \mathrm{Set}$ be a simplicial object with no nondegenerate cells except in degree $0$. Why the (composition of) degeneracy map $t_n\colon X_0\to X_n$ is **injective**? Is this $t_n$ unique? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any simplicial set, because of the simplicial identity $d_j s_j = 1$, each degeneracy map $s_j$ is injective, and therefore any composite of degeneracy maps is injective.

For any 0-simplex $v$, you can use the simplicial identity $s_i s_{j} = s_{j+1} s_i$ for $i<j+1$ to show that $t_n v = s_{n-1} \circ \dots \circ s_1 \circ s_0 v$, if $t_n$ is as in your question.

Edit: using the simplicial identity, one can show that any composite of degeneracies can be written as a composite $s_{i_1} s_{i_2} ...$ where the subscripts strictly decrease: $i_j > i_{j+1}$ for each $j$. Then use the fact that on $X_k$, the possible degeneracies are $s_0$, ..., $s_k$, to deduce that if you start with $X_0$, there is only one possible composite of degeneracy maps.

Comment: I do not follow. How did you use $s_i s_{j} = s_{j+1} s_i$ for $i<j+1$ to show that $t_n v = s_{n-1} \circ \dots \circ s_1 \circ s_0 v$, if $t_n$ is as in my question? What are $s_k$ here?

Comment: Also, it follows $s_1\circ s_0=s_0\circ s_0=s_1\circ s_1$. This is weird.

Comment: The $s_k$ are the degeneracy maps, $s_k: X_n \to X_{n+1}$, $0 \leq k \leq n$.

Comment: Do you have right the simplicial identity? It yields, as stated, that $s_1\circ s_0 = s_0 \circ s_0 = s_1 \circ s_1$. It has apparently wrong domain and codomain.Also what is $t_n$ when $s_n$ are given?

Comment: Yes, I have the right simplicial identity. Check your favorite reference or do an internet search to verify. (The domain of the simplicial identity is $X_k$, the codomain is $X_{k+2}$.)

Comment: But [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set) that do not mention any identity where all four letters are $s$. There is always $d_i \circ s_j$ or $d_i\circ d_j$ on the l.h.s. Search for "Face and degeneracy maps" on that wikipedia page.

Comment: #5 on the wikipedia page is wrong: the left side is $d_i s_j$ and the right side is $s_{j+1} s_i$ – different domains and codomains. Mine is the correct version of theirs. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+identities, for example.

Comment: OK. And what is the relation between $t_n$'s and $s_n$'s?

Comment: $t_n$ is not standard notation, so from your question I took $t_n$ to be a composite of $n$ degeneracy maps: $t_n$ is a composite of the maps $s_k$ for various $k$.

Comment: And **how** precisely have you used that simplicial identity  $s_i s_{j} = s_{j+1} s_i$ for $i<j+1$ to sort $s_k$'s in $t_n v = s_{n-1} \circ \dots \circ s_1 \circ s_0 v$?

Comment: See the edit to the answer. Also try it yourself with $n=1, 2, 3$ to see how it works.

Comment: I almost understand. But what if you have 2 (or more) , non-identical, strictly decresing composition of degeneracies?

Comment: If the domain is $X_0$, you can’t.

Comment: Does the proof that if the domain is $X_0$ I can't use **induction** on $k$'s?